# Generate a list of a given length with fake elements. Django

Tags: python, django

I'm developing my app with django and in one of my views I have a given number (nbr). I would like to know if it is possible to generate a list of length 'nbr', filled with 'nbr' fake elements.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
new_list = [None]*nbr
```

This idiom is mostly used for immutable objects.  For mutable objects, typically

```
new_list = [ mutable_object_factory() for _ in range(nbr) ]
```

is used (unless you really know what you're doing :)

Comment: Why bother with two different syntaxes if one works always? :)

Comment: @tvdien -- They do slightly different things.  The first is more succinct.  Finally, since both idioms are common, it's good to know both (e.g. when reading other people's code)

Comment: @tvdien -- there is an important disctinction between the two because if you do new_list = obj * nbr you are creating nbr number references to obj. That is almost certainly not what is wanted as changing new_list[0].something will change the something attribute in all the referenced copies of obj.

Comment: It might be worth noting the side-effect of the use of `_` in interactive mode, that `_` no longer will store the result of the previous command

Comment: @rorycl That's exactly why I commented. I think hardly anyone wants a list of references to the same mutable object. Therefore it is safer to always use the list comprehension, because it is much more likely to give the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
[fake_element for n in xrange(nbr)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the random elements are stored in a list called `choices`, you can use `random.choice`

```
In [1]: choices = ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [2]: myList = [random.choice(choices) for x in xrange(10)]

In [3]: myList
Out[3]: ['b', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a']
```

Comment: I just realized that I think I misread the "fake" elements of the question as random elements.